# How to tick those group by fetching groups based on user id in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, bootstrap-modal

In the below image the user is in three groups so I want while updating the user the groups that user in should be checked.
how can I achieve this ?

[image]

I am unable to get how to achieve this in Django for now I fetching the all groups from database.

```
  {% for group in groups %}     
  <tr>
                             
  <td>{{group.name}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="add_group[]" id="group-{{group.id}}" value="{{group.id}}"></td>
                                          
  </tr> 
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: how is your connection between the user and the group? how do you access users other info in the modal? add more codes of your modal

Comment: How can u distinguish the groups by which is to be ticked?

Comment: Using default group and user modal

Comment: One user can be in diff. groups so suppose the user in three groups so At the time of updating the three group should be ticked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{% if ... %}` inside the tag by this way:

```html
<td>
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        name="add_group[]" 
        id="group-{{group.id}}" 
        value="{{group.id}}"
        {% if condition %}
        checked
        {% endif %}
    >
</td>
```

Here if the condition satisfies you can see it as ticked.